# "Unknown compiler option 'preserveValueImports'.ts" error when making a sveltekit project

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, svelte, sveltekit

[image: Image of the error]

Whenever I create a sveltekit project with tyepscript, I always have the "Unknown compiler option 'preserveValueImports'.ts" appear in the tsconfig.json file. The error appears over the '"strict": true' line as seen in the image.

I'm using typescript version 4.9.4 and have tried to downgrade it to 4.8.4, but the error still persists. This is my first time trying out sveltekit and typescript, so I'm not sure if I installed them wrong, but all I did was installed typescript globally with npm and then created svelte project with pnpm. I also had created the svelte project with npm but the error still appears.

Answer (score 1):

This error was solved on reddit by updating visual studio code to the latest version (1.74.2), as VS code uses the bundled version of typescript by default.